# How do I detect collisions between a KinematicBody2D and a RigidBody2D in Godot?

Tags: signals, godot, gdscript

I am trying to make a simple game in Godot where a wall falls down and the player has to dodge it. The wall is a RigidBody2D with a sprite and CollisionShape2D attached. The player is a KinematicBody2D with a sprite and CollisionShape2D attached. The main scene is a Node2D with the player and wall as children of it. I have managed to get the player to detect collisions but when I emit a signal (which is connected to the wall script), the wall does nothing. I have already tried using the `body_entered` signal in the player script, but nothing happens. Does anybody know how to fix this?

My player script:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var speed = 1300
var velocity = Vector2()
signal game_over

func get_input():
velocity = Vector2()
if Input.is_action_pressed('d'):
    velocity.x += 1
if Input.is_action_pressed('a'):
    velocity.x -= 1
velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed

func _physics_process(delta):
get_input()

move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2(0, 0), false, 4, 0.785, false)

for index in get_slide_count():
    var collision = get_slide_collision(index)
    if collision.collider.is_in_group("Level"):
        death()

func death():
    emit_signal("game_over")
    hide()
```

The wall script:

```
extends RigidBody2D

func _on_Player_game_over():
    print("player collided") #example to see if collision is detected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell why your code is not working. However, I would do it differently: Instead of emitting a signal, call a method on the `collider`:

```
    if collision.collider.is_in_group("Level"):
        collision.collider._on_Player_game_over()
        death()
```

*It is probably worth giving the method a better name.*

By the way, you can also check if the collider has the method. For example:

```
    if collision.collider.has_method("_on_Player_game_over"):
        collision.collider._on_Player_game_over()
        death()
```

---

*The rest of this answer is explaining how to handle the collision on the `RigidBody2D` with the `"body_entered"` signal.*

- First make sure the `RigidBody2D` has `contact_monitor` set to `true`.
- Also set its `contacts_reported` to a value greater than `0`. There can be multiple contacts with the same body, and you need to consider possible contacts with other bodies. *A value around `8` is probably OK.*
- Have the `"body_entered"` signal of the `RigidBody2D` connected *to itself*.
- in the method in the `RigidBody2D` that handles the `"body_entered"` signal you would get a `body` parameter:

  ```
  func _on_Wall_body_enter(body):
      print("Collision")
  ```

  *By the way, I would like to encourage to take advantage of collision layer and masks. So you can narrow what collisions the `RigidBody2D` even checks for.*
- Then you can filter what body it is. You can, for example:

  - Use the name:

    ```
    func _on_Wall_body_enter(body):
        if body.name == "Player":
            print("Collision with player")
    ```
  - Use a group:

    ```
    func _on_Wall_body_enter(body):
        if body.is_in_group("Player"):
            print("Collision with player")
    ```
  - Use a class name (this requires to add a `class_name` to the player):

    ```
    func _on_Wall_body_enter(body):
        if body is Player:
            print("Collision with player")
    ```
  - Check for a method:

    ```
    func _on_Wall_body_enter(body):
        if body.has_method("death"):
            print("Collision with player")
    ```
- And, of course, you can call a method on it notify. For example:

  ```
  func _on_Wall_body_enter(body):
      if body is Player:
          body.death()
  ```

  Or

  ```
  func _on_Wall_body_enter(body):
      if body.has_method("death"):
          body.death()
  ```